# IONIC 2 - Google Maps API don't working with browser after hosting

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic2

My Google Maps API JavaScript doesn't work with browser after hosting.
My hosting is OVH France.

Console WARNING:

> Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys

Console ERROR:

> Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error
> _.Pb @ js:38

But I have an API Key registered and activated.

```
        <ion-col>
          <div #map id="map"></div>
        </ion-col>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=initMap"></script>
```

The function on .ts file search on Firebase event address and show in the maps.
The Maps it's **OK** on localhost web browser and Android build (.apk).

Comment: Hi, in the GoogleMapsAPi call, Do you add your API KEY to work it?

Comment: Hi Pablo! yes, I added the API KEY generated. The Maps it works on localhost:8100 (with ionic serve command) and Android (ionic cordova build android command). But, when I upload the 'www' folder to hosting the maps don't work, and the console show WARNING: NoApiKeys + ERROR: MissingKeyMapError.

Comment: And, did you assign permissions at console.developers.google.com?

Answer (score 0):

I never use keys yet my G-maps work like a charm... what's the catch?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
.GMap {
 position:absolute;
 left: 50px;
 top: 50px;
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
}

</style>
</head>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function GoogleMap(){
var mapCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(33.54749540415048,37.81249999999999);
var mapOptions={center:mapCenter, zoom:2, mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"),mapOptions);
var Custom=[{"featureType":"all","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"hue":"#2fa8d5"},{"saturation":-17},{"lightness":5},{"gamma":1.531},{"invert_lightness":false}]}];
map.setOptions({styles:Custom});
var infostr='Hello!';
var infowindow=new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:infostr});
infowindow.setPosition(mapCenter);
infowindow.open(map);
}

window.onload=GoogleMap;

</script>
 <div id="mapcanvas" class="GMap"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! I want to use API Key for use the Google Maps API JavaScript on my project (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?hl=pt-br). The Maps search event address on Firebase and show in the maps

Answer (score 0):

And, did you assign permissions at console.developers.google.com?

[image]

Comment: Hi! Yes, I added HTTP permissions for domain.

Comment: You know if you can consult external web services from your web hosting provider?

Comment: I tried on 2 different hostings and the error continue. The localhost and .apk for Android keeps running

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

The script of the Maps must be added in the **index.html** file of the Ionic project to run correctly. 
I was using directly in component, so it was giving error.